# Delete child and update parent list

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a parent component with a list of `transactions`.  They are displayed like so:

```
<table class="table awaken-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <transaction-row style="display:table-row;line-height:32px;" *ngFor="let transaction of transactions | orderDate" [transaction]="transaction"></transaction-row>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

...and `transaction-row` looks like so:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'transaction-row',
    template: `
            <td text-center style="font-size:16px">
                <i class="fa fa-trash danger" style="font-size:20px;" (click)=deleteAlert()></i>
            </td>
    `
})

export class TransactionRow {
    @Input() transaction: any;

    ...
}
```

When I click on the icon and call `deleteAlert()` I successfully delete the item but it remains on the list as `transactions` has not been updated.

**How do I remove this `transaction` from the list of `transactions`**

(I'm sure it has to do with `@Output` I just am very unfamiliar with how to use it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use EventEmitter in child Component like this:

```
import { Input, Output, Component, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'transaction-row',
    template: `
            <td text-center style="font-size:16px">
                <i class="fa fa-trash danger" style="font-size:20px;" (click)=deleteAlert()></i>
            </td>
    `
})

export class TransactionRow {
    @Input() transaction: any;
    @Output() deleteRow: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
    ...

    deleteAlert(){
      ...
      this.deleteRow.emit(this.transaction);
    }
}
```

in html listen to deleteRow event

```
<transaction-row style="display:table-row;line-height:32px;" *ngFor="let transaction of transactions | orderDate" [transaction]="transaction" (deleteRow)="onDeleteRow($event)"></transaction-row>
```

and finally in your parent component splice transactions array:

```
...

   onDeleteRow(item: any) {
       this.transactions.splice(this.transactions.indexOf(item),1);
   }
...
```

Comment: more advanced approach is to use Service, shared with both components. Which approach is better? Depends on complexity. regards